# Is the following demonstration for the limit valid

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have the following limit:

$$
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}{\frac{|x|\ln(1+y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}
$$

I want to show that it is $0$. I will use the Squeeze theorem.

$$
\bigg|\frac{|x|\ln(1+y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\bigg| \le \frac{|x||\ln(1+y)|}{|x|} = |\ln(1+y)|
$$

Which is $0$ for $y\rightarrow0$.

Is it valid reasoning?

Comment: There should be |ln(1+y)|, other than that everything seems fine.

Comment: @MathPanda Yup corrected the mistake. Thanks for the feedback. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof sounds good. Well done!

Alternatively, I propose a very slightly different approach to obtain the same result by noticing that
\begin{align*}
|x| = \sqrt{x^{2}} \leq \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}} \Rightarrow 0\leq \left|\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}}\right| \leq 1 \Rightarrow 0 \leq \left|\frac{x\ln(1 + y)}{\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}}\right| \leq |\ln(1 + y)|
\end{align*}

You can then apply the squeeze theorem.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Great insight. Never thought of using the identity $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ the way you purposed.

Comment: @Harry I am glad to help!